# Javascript DOM vs. Canvas for Mobile Game Development

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am planning to make a mobile game using the Phonegap framework. My current idea is to have a ball and be able to move the ball using the accelerometer on the phone. I also plan to have other objects in the game (eg: enemy's, walls, etc).

**Methods:**

1. **HTML5** - I have done some research and have seen html5 canvas being used a
   lot for these kinds of games.
2. **jQuery** - I have also looked into jQuery and have seen some really nice
   example of games written in jQuery.

I have no experience with html5 and was looking into the canvas tag. From what I understand, (correct me if I'm wrong) the canvas tag needs to be cleared in order to move an image or shape. While jQuery can alter the CSS for an image and be able to move it using CSS.

After playing around with a sample jQuery game with similar characteristics, I noticed that the game tends to lag every once in a while. I would prefer a method that does not lag the game.

What approach should I take to make a game with the characteristics mentioned above? If you know of another method that would work with the Phonegap framework, please let me know.

Comment: JQuery is javascript. The canvas element is written using Javascript.

Comment: By jQuery, he means using lots of DOM elements instead of a `<canvas>`.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I need a method that is easy to program in. One of the reason I was not preferring canvas was because it needs to be cleared every time something moves on the canvas. (correct me if I'm wrong). I would prefer a method where if I wanted to move lets say am image, I could just give it the new x y coordinates and it would move instead of having to worry about clearing the canvas etc.

Comment: I think the question should be "Canvas vs Non-Canvas". Either way, you'll be using jQuery or some other js library.

Comment: @tybro0103 "**DOM vs Canvas for mobile games**".

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the canvas does need to be cleared each time or the graphical elements will just keep being added to the canvas (can make for some cool effects). jQuery is generally more useful for web development than game development while HTML5 is very versatile. I would strongly recommend doing your base game development in HTML5, but there is no reason you can't use jQuery along side it, where appropriate and/or convenient.

Comment: When you say base game development. Do you mean use the canvas as the main game board but still use jQuery to move elements?

Comment: jQuery isn't really designed for game development, and doesn't really have many options for working with `canvas` (yet).  Check out other libraries here: http://html5games.com/resources/ including the already mentioned Game Maker HTML5

Comment: Yes. I don't know the nature of the kind of game you wish to make, but the game I'm working on has the main 'board' as an html5 canvas and various other elements such as the in game chat, store, etc outside of the canvas. I use jQuery to allow the user to show/hide those elements and change their on-screen positions.